# return a class directly from a linq query

Tags: c#, linq, c#-3.0, linq-to-xml

I'm still new to LINQ. Is it possible to do the following:

e.g., I have a class:

```
public class Person
{
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Now i want to return it as a class object by reading, say, an xml file's contents and returning it.

So if i read this
xml file:

```
<person>
    <firstname></firstname>
    <lastname></lastname>
</person>
```

Read Person (say this belongs to a People class):

```
public static Person ReadPerson(xmlpath)
{
    XDocument xd = XDocument.Load(xmlpath);
    var person = (from p in xd.Descendants("person")
                  select new Person
                  {
                      FirstName = p.Element("firstname").value,
                      LastName = p.Element("lastname").value
                  });
    return person as Person;
}
```

Now if i do the following elsewhere:

```
Person p = new Person();
p = People.Person(xmlpath);
Response.Write(p.FirstName);
```

Here, p.FirstName returns a null exception. Which i understand is because the linq query returned an empty class.

So my question is, is there anyway to directly add stuff into a class within a query and return it ***WITHOUT running a foreach loop and adding everything in manually***? (like the following:)

```
Person p = new Person();
foreach (var x in person)
{
    p.FirstName = x.FirstName;
    p.LastName = x.LastName;
}
```

Sorry if this is a stupid question.

Thanks

Comment: If p.FirstName is throwing NullReferenceException that doesn't mean that LINQ returns an empty class, it can as well return null. Try to check p for null and please send the stacktrace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to distinguish between reading a *sequence* of items and reading a *single* item. Currently the `person` variable in `ReadPerson` is actually of type `IEnumerable<Person>` - you're returning `person as Person` which will be null, because that sequence isn't *actually* an instance of `Person`. If you'd used a cast instead of `as`, you'd have seen that earlier - but the very fact that you had to do *anything* to the types should be a warning that you weren't quite doing the right thing.

I suspect you actually want either this:

```
public static IEnumerable<Person> ReadPeople(xmlpath)
{
    XDocument xd = XDocument.Load(xmlpath);
    return from p in xd.Descendants("person")
           select new Person
           {
               FirstName = p.Element("firstname").value,
               LastName = p.Element("lastname").value
           });
}
```

or this:

```
public static Person ReadPerson(xmlpath)
{
    XDocument xd = XDocument.Load(xmlpath);
    XElement element = xd.Descendants("person").First();
    return new Person
           {
               FirstName = element.Element("firstname").value,
               LastName = element.Element("lastname").value
           });
}
```

You should also consider what you want to happen if there are *no* `person` elements, or *multiple* person elements. The `First`, `FirstOrDefault`, `Single` and `SingleOrDefault` methods will be useful for you here.

Answer (score 2):

From how I read it, all you need is:

```
public static IEnumerable<Person> ReadPeople(xmlpath)
{
    XDocument xd = XDocument.Load(xmlpath);
    return (from p in xd.Descendants("person")
            select new Person
            {
                FirstName = (string)p.Element("firstname"),
                LastName = (string)p.Element("lastname")
            });
}
```

This addresses:

- the issue of returning *multiple* descendants
- the issue of firstname/lastname not being specified

if you intent there to only be one, then use `Single()` / `First()` / `SingleOrDefault()` / `FirstOrDefault()`.

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem! `person` in ReadPerson method is not instance of `Person` class, but collection (`IEnumerable<Person>`) and casting to `Person` returns `null`.

Answer (score 0):

The following line has the invalid casting problem. You should let the compiler to help you (see my modified function).

```
return person as Person;
```

You should return a list of persons instead of just a single person. If you are sure that only one person is in the xml, you can call Single() instead of ToList().

```
public static List<Person> ReadPerson(xmlpath)
{
    XDocument xd = XDocument.Load(xmlpath);
    /*var person = (from p in xd.Descendants("person")
                  select new Person
                  {
                      FirstName = p.Element("firstname").value,
                      LastName = p.Element("lastname").value
                  });*/
    List<Person> persons = (from p in xd.Descendants("person")
                  select new Person
                  {
                      FirstName = p.Element("firstname").value,
                      LastName = p.Element("lastname").value
                  }).ToList();
    return persons;
}
```